# reducing the number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970

Tags: javascript

This script produces a huge number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970.(for example 1392552803373):

```
<html>
 <body>

   <p id="demo"> the number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970.</p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   <script>
   function myFunction()
   {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=new Date().getTime();
   }
   </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to reduce this number by setting new base time to January 1, 2014? Or another way? My goal is to use `new Date().getTime()` in different parts of script and receive smaller number of milliseconds based on steady time stamp.

Comment: What would be the advantage of setting a new baseline?

Comment: You've explained your desired solution, but not the problem. What problem specifically is Unix time causing you that makes you want to fundamentally change the way it works?

Comment: Just subtract the  number of millisseconds between 2014 and 1970, but seems well pointless and could easily lead to errors.

Comment: are you asking us to make time go slower? pffft i wish

Comment: @ChristianVarga i want to sent this numbers to server and keep them in int variables on server side. I dont need so huge numbers.

Comment: This difference is `Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1) === 1388534400000`

Comment: @maciekm: in case you transmit those dates to a server, you should send a valid date format, i.e. 2014-02-14 instead of the millis till a given point in time.

Comment: @maciekm That doesn't make sense, because 1392552803373 is already an `int`. You're not solving any problem, because no problem exists. Creating your own custom format for time that doesn't follow any existing format or conventions is going to cause massive headaches for development and maintenance. Again, whatever you think you're trying to solve, you're not. Storing numbers like 1392552803373 is trivial, if you think you're going to get performance gains by implementing smaller numbers, you're mistaken.

Comment: @ChristianVarga wait a second, i go to check int range again...

Comment: @home how you send dates to a server depends on what you're trying to do with them; it might be easier to send it in an ISO format, it might be easier to send it as some int. The most important thing is the client is sending the same format as the server is expecting.

Comment: @maciekm Typical use is for storing Unix time, so there's nothing to check, but assuming int64 it's 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 signed or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 unsigned. Trust me, if it wasn't efficient, or if there was a better way, people wouldn't be using it. I would also recommend looking into DateTime values instead of milliseconds as others have suggested. It really depends on what you're using the time values for, but chances are you don't really need to use Unix time.

Comment: @ChristianVarga sorry,I wasn't clear, by "int" i meant 4 bytes variable, thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the Date API with your own.

the Date object can receive any formatted date. use this to calculate the difference from now.

Create a function (or object), that returns the relevant time.

**Example**

```
function myGetTime() {
   return new Date() - new Date('January 1, 2014');
}
```

Comment: It may be wiser to use `1388534400000` and avoid timezone issues.

Comment: Both dates are computed in the same timezone, this shouldn't be an issue as it's a relative time-frame

Comment: The **unix epoch** is the same in any timezone though, and we are talking about _ms since the unix epoch_

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create your own function. Just reduce the ms in your function and return the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write your own function that returns what you want. E.g. you may use 01.01.2014 as a base, or you may return the time in seconds instead of millis, etc. Why don't you do that? What's the problem?
2. You might replace getTime() with your own implementation by changing the prototype. But this will have effect on ALL other scripts that you might use in your page. This may cause more new problems that it solves.

Comment: "Why don't you do that? What's the problem?" The problem is i am still beginner in javascript :)